# QTP can not recognize the flex object?

Tags: apache-flex, testing, flex3, qtp

I am using Quicktest professional 11 trial version. I have a flex application for testing. When I try to record action performed on the flex application. QTP stores it as MacroMediaFlashPlayerActiveX rather than the origin button or link. I am using flex 3.5.0 and internet explorer 7. How can I do this??

Comment: Have you included automation libs in your application?

Comment: oh, I remember about your previous questions on Flex automation. Why did you choose QTP at the end?

Comment: Yes I added the automation library path in the compiler arguments. I did not choose anyone yet. I am still in the process of testing that which one is better. I shifted to QTP from flexMonkey because it was not recording some of the action which I need. so QTP is doing the job but it treated the whole page as one MacromediaflasplayerActiveX object.

Comment: I am adding these libraries in the compiler arguments.    -include-libraries "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.5.0\frameworks\libs\automation.swc"

Comment: @Brian Bishop: Yes it happens frequently in my case. In my case I have tabs and other controls on my webPage. FlexMonkey skip actions performed on then. So when one have recorded such test there is no way to play it back. QTP does not skip any action but marks the object as MacroMediaFlashPlayerActiveX object. If you have any suggestion please let me know.. Thanks Brian

Comment: Have you tried using Firefox or Chrome? Im sure I will have the same problem when its downloaded

Comment: yeah I tried but give me the same results. I am wondering why QTP don't recognize some object and work for others..

Comment: @Brian -> You must provide a different automationName for each new UI component added at runtime

Comment: @Safraz : On what control does it happen?

Comment: I figured out the problem...this problem occurs when you disable childMouse on the component. I turned it on and its working.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the solution. It will be great to share with you.

Testing Using QTP:

-->Install QTP_plugin for flex. This can be found in install directory of flex.

-->Include the following libraries in the compiler arguments.

-include-libraries "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.5.0\frameworks\libs\automation.swc" "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.5.0\frameworks\libs\automation_agent.swc" "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.5.0\frameworks\libs\qtp.swc" "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.5.0\frameworks\libs\automation_dmv.swc"

and you are good to go. Remember those components which has ChildMouse property set to false will be shown in the testing as MacroMediaFlashPlayerActiveX object.